# Compact Tableview

Tags: gui-design, interaction-design, tables

I'm currently working on a web application that includes a kind of table where each row can be expanded and collapsed, respectively. I added the picture below that you can see what I mean:

[image]

Now all the cells with the colorful hyphens can be checked. The problem is that the large amount of cells may become quite confusing. So do you know some kind of ui-element that can be used to group the elements more appropriately?

Comment: Do the colors have any meaning? What does the hypen talks about?

Comment: No, the colors are just eye candy. If you click on one of the hyphens, a tick appears like on the image.

Comment: What's the thought behind showing a hypen and when user click on it; bringing a tick?

Comment: Who is the user and what is their goal?

Comment: What does the tick represent? The use of iconography for each column means the user needs to learn what the icon represents, and I assume that the tick means the record matches the category represented by the column iconography

Comment: There is a lot of visual noise represented by the coloured hyphens. You could consider alternative row shading to help the user accurately scan from record on the left along the row to the right.

Answer (score 1):

#### Additional Menu

One of the main sources of potential confusion here is that an individual hyphen in a cell can end up a long way from the icon in the menu bar that lets the user know what it's for.

Showing the same menu bar when the user expands a section could alleviate this.

#### 'Frozen Row' or 'Sticky' Menu

You might also consider replicating the functionality of Microsoft Excel's frozen rows.

That is, when the user scrolls down so that the menu will disappear to the top, the menu 'sticks' to the top of the browser window, so that it scrolls with the user.

[image]

Comment: Interesting, thans for the proposal!